# SSIS Package Hangs Randomly on Execution

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm working with an SSIS package that itself calls multiple SSIS packages and hangs periodically during execution.

This is a once-a-day package that runs every evening and collects new and changed records from our census databases and migrates them into the staging tables of our data warehouse.  Each dimension has its own package that we call through this package.

So, the package looks like

1. Get current change version
2. Load last change version
3. Identify changed values
4. a-z - Move changed records to staging tables (Separate packages)
5. Save change version for future use

All of those are execute SQL tasks except for the moving records tasks which are twenty some execute package tasks (data move tasks), which are executed somewhat in parallel.  (Max four at a time.)

The strange part is that it almost always fails when executed by the SQL agent (using a proxy user) or dtexec, but never fails when I run the package through Visual Studio.  I've added logging so that I can see where it stops, but it's inconsistent.

We didn't see any of this while working in our development / training environments, but the volume of data is considerably smaller.  I wonder if we're just doing too much at once.

I may - to test - execute the tasks serially through the SQL Server agent to see if it's a problem with a package calling a package , but I'd rather not do this because we have a relatively short time in the evening to do this for seven database servers.

I'm slightly new to SSIS, so any advice would be appreciated.

Justin

Comment: What error messages can you pull from the job history?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server (for both your live environment and testing/dev) and what version of BIDS are you using?